# How can I make JavaScript output a string without evaluating numbers?

Tags: javascript, css

I have this string stored in a variable:

```
const width = 'calc(16.666666666666668% - 3%)';
```

If I try to apply this value to an element as a style, like this:

```
document.body.style.width = width;
```

It outputs:

```
width: calc(13.6667%);
```

How can I make it add the correct value to the element?

It should be outputting:

```
width: calc(16.666666666666668% - 3%);
```

Comment: correct value === calc(13.6667)?

Comment: @AliaksandrPitkevich, no, it should be outputting the string as is - `'calc(16.666666666666668% - 3%)'` this is a CSS expression that must be evaluated by CSS after the DOM has rendered.

Comment: You are missing a end parentheses in your first string, not sure if that matters.

Comment: @gkgkgkgk yep just fixed, was a typo - issue still persists

Comment: _“this is a CSS expression that must be evaluated by CSS after the DOM has rendered”_ - since both of your values are given in percent here, this can be calculated up-front without changing anything whatsoever regarding the final result. Now if you had f.e. `calc(100% - 10px)`, then that would be a different matter - and pretty sure your browser will handle _that_ case differently to begin with.

Comment: @EdmundReed thats really strange.... try concating the strings: width = 'calc(' + '16.66...%' + '- 3%'; Otherwise, you have me stumped.

Comment: @CBroe Actually the `3%` value can be any size dimension, including `px`, so I need to use CSS's `calc()`.

Comment: Put everything into a `div` and it works fine for me

Comment: Have you _tried_ it with two different units …? My Chromium-based browser shows the behavior you are complaining about for two operands given in %, but as soon as I change one of the units, that effect does not occur any more to begin with.

Comment: @CBroe you're right that it works with mixed units, but given that the unit has the potential to be either `px` or `%`, I still need to have it working with `calc()` and two percentage values. Otherwise I would have to perform some additional logic to determine if the 2 values are the same dimension and change the behaviour accordingly.

Comment: _“I still need to have it working with calc() and two percentage values”_ - but it _does_ work? You still have not managed to show us how/in what situation this would constitute an _actual_ problem. _“It outputs: [...]”_ - is _this_ what you actually care about, what value you get when you read it _back_?

Comment: Right now you are acting as if paying a ten dollar check with one ten dollar bill, or two five dollar bills, would make any significant difference. (Not saying it doesn’t make _any_, but until you can tell us what that significance is to you in this particular situation, this whole question makes very little sense IMHO.)

Comment: @CBroe actually I think you're right. I was confused for some reason and thought that `calc(16.6% - 3%)`; would render a different computed width to `calc(13.6%)`, but it doesn't, which seems pretty obvious now.